# How would I block or spoof the blur event listener?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I've already put together a small web console script that worked on one website but it doesn't seem to work on another. I guess what I'm really wondering is if there is a more effective way to go about doing this.

```js
window.addEventListener("blur", function(event) { 
 event.stopPropagation();
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events that do fire directly on *Window* don't have a "*Capture Phase*".

If you look at the [Event dispatch and DOM event flow](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-flow) graphic, you can see that this flow starts at *Window*, and thus such events will already be in the "*Target Phase*" from the first step.

This means that on such events, the `capture` flag is useless, because all event listeners will fire in the "*Target Phase*" anyway, so **you can't stop the propagation of the event to previously set handlers**, since they will fire before your capture handler.

```js
const phases_dict = {
  [Event.CAPTURING_PHASE]: 'Capturing Phase',
  [Event.AT_TARGET]: 'Target Phase',
  [Event.BUBBLING_PHASE]: 'Bubbling Phase'
};

// First listener defined without capturing flag, will fire first anyway
window.addEventListener( 'blur', evt => {
  const current_phase = phases_dict[ evt.eventPhase ];
  console.log( 'bubble blur is in', current_phase );
}, { capture: false } ); // fire at bubbling phase

// Second listener with capturing flag
window.addEventListener( 'blur', evt => {
  // This one will also capture the events on Elements in the Document
  // For our case, we only want the one on Window
  if( evt.currentTarget === evt.target ) {
    const current_phase = phases_dict[ evt.eventPhase ];
    console.log( 'capture blur is in', current_phase );
  }
}, { capture: true } ); // fire at capturing phase


// To show that bubbling events work as intended
// We also register click events
window.addEventListener( 'click', evt => {
  const current_phase = phases_dict[ evt.eventPhase ];
  console.log( 'bubble click is in', current_phase );
}, { capture: false } ); // fire at bubbling phase
window.addEventListener( 'click', evt => {
  const current_phase = phases_dict[ evt.eventPhase ];
  console.log( 'capture click is in', current_phase );
}, { capture: true } ); // fire at capturing phase
```

```html
<pre>Click anywhere in this frame then click somewhere else in SO's page to trigger focus event</pre>
```

Note that you can stop the propagation of Elements' *blur* events, but not the one of Window.
You will have to find an other way to block your current listeners, maybe by using a flag variable?

Comment: So from what I can tell @Kaiido you're talking about doing something like this [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/6xheg5/eventlistener_how_to_set_a_flag_on_a/). The only problem with that is I'm trying to block the listener on a website which is not my own so I can't change the initial JavaScript. Thanks for the in-depth explanation.

Comment: @Papu yes that's what I'm suggesting, but since you don't have access to the page's scripts, the only solution would be to run yours before. This can be done through user-scripts, have a look at TamperMonkey, they offer an `@run-at` option.